# Facebook "Like Box": how to make it work with my Facebook Page URL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox

I would like to use Facebook's "Like Box" social plugin, for which one can get the code here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

However, when I populate the field entitled "Facebook Page URL" with the URL for my Facebook page, I get an error message in place of where the "Like Box" preview should show up.  The error message is:

"Could not retrieve id for the specified page. Please verify correct href was passed in."

I've entered the URL exactly as it appears in the address bar when one navigates to my Facebook profile in a browser.  Does this have something to do with my privacy settings on Facebook? If so, which one(s) in particular?  I don't want to have to fiddle around with all of them and I can't seem to find one that explicitly says anything like, "allow external websites to connect to your profile using plugins."

Thanks in advance for any help on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add like button for facebook profiles, its only for pages. Have you ever liked somebody's profile??

Comment: HA! Wow do I feel silly.  Ok, well thanks for setting me straight!